# How to set column width in JTable/JXTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, column-width, jxtable

My application consists of several JTables resp. JXTables. The goal is to store column width and reload them on start up.

But the following code does nothing change on the column widths of the tables:

```
tblTasks.getColumn(1).setWidth(36);
```

and also this one does nothing:

```
tblTasks.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(36);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 15):

> But the following code does nothing change on the column widths of the
>   tables:
>
> ```
> tblTasks.getColumn(1).setWidth(36);
> ```
>
> and also this one does nothing:
>
> ```
> tblTasks.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(36);
> ```
>
> Any ideas ?

.

proper constructor is `JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(36);`

for example

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TableRowHeight {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("p*s*s*s*s*t*t");
    private String[] columnNames = {"one", "two", "Playing with", "four", "five",};
    private String[][] data = {
        {"aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee",},
        {"bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa",},
        {"cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb",},
        {"dddddd", "eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc",},
        {"eeeeeee", "aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd",}};
    private JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    private TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    private Stack<TableColumn> colDeleted = new Stack<TableColumn>();
    private JButton restoreButton = new JButton("Restore Column Size");
    private JButton hideButton = new JButton("Set Column Size to Zero");
    private JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete Column");
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Restore Column");

    public TableRowHeight() {
        table.setRowMargin(4);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 20));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        for (int i = 0; i < (tcm.getColumnCount()); i++) {
            tcm.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(150);
        }
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        restoreButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
            }
        });
        hideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(000);
            }
        });
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (table.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                    TableColumn colToDelete = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.getColumnCount() - 1);
                    table.removeColumn(colToDelete);
                    table.validate();
                    colDeleted.push(colToDelete);
                    addButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (colDeleted.size() > 0) {
                    table.addColumn(colDeleted.pop());
                    table.validate();
                    deleteButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    addButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(hideButton);
        btnPanel.add(restoreButton);
        btnPanel.add(deleteButton);
        btnPanel.add(addButton);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableRowHeight frame = new TableRowHeight();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
table.getColumn("Column Name").setMaxWidth(36);
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did is setting the minimum width to a value for each column. For the preferred width of the last column I choose Integer.MAX_VALUE which will push all the other columns to their minimum size.

This is a snippet from my project:

```
ruleTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
ruleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(25);
ruleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(125);
ruleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(175);
ruleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Hope it will help you and maybe others... For you it may be a little late ;-P

Answer (score 1):

```
table.getColumn("Column Name").setMinWidth(36);
```